# Execute function after inner $http call finishes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my code I am calling this function `loadAllOrders();`. This is the skeleton of its implementation,

```
$scope.loadAllOrders = function() {
    orderSvc.GetAllOrders().then(function(response) {
       // Does a bunch of stuff here
    });
}
```

`GetAllOrders()` uses a `$http` to get data from a database. `loadAllOrders()` then formats all the data and inserts them into an `ng-repeat`.

I want to be able to call a function when `loadAllOrders()` has finished. For example,

```
$scope.loadAllOrders().then(
    //I am doing something
);
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: your `promise` to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom promise for loadAllOrders in angular JS

You have to inject **$q** service as a dependency on your controllers or service

```
$scope.loadAllOrders = function() {
var deferred = $q.defer();
    orderSvc.GetAllOrders().then(function(response) {
       // Does a bunch of stuff here
deferred.resolve(response);
    });
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I then execute the function after the promise is returned?

Comment: $scope.loadAllOrders().then(function(result) {
   
}); same as like you have written on your question

Comment: Beware of the promise anti-pattern. Just return `orderSvc.GetAllOrders()` to return the promise.